# Storing Pointers to a Struct in An Array ? iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, memory-management, malloc

I have the below code in my app which mallocs memory to a struct object. This method is called several times in the code, each time mallocing memory for a new Vector3D object.

What I want to do is capture the pointer to the malloced ShapeClass object (a C struct) so that I can later free each object in my dealloc method.

Can anyone advise me how I can add the pointer to an array ?

Thank you.

```
vectorCount = [floatArray.array count] / 3;
        ShapeClass *vectorArray = malloc(sizeof(Vector3D) * vectorCount);
        for (int i=0; i<vectorCount; i++) {
            vectorArray[i].x = [[floatArray.array objectAtIndex:(i*3)] floatValue];
            vectorArray[i].y = [[floatArray.array objectAtIndex:(i*3)+1] floatValue];
            vectorArray[i].z = [[floatArray.array objectAtIndex:(i*3)+2] floatValue];
        }
        return vectorArray;
// I WANT TO INSERT SOMETHING HERE TO CAPTURE THE POINTER TO vectorArray - E.G ADD IT TO AN ARRAY ?
    }
}
return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[NSValue valueWithPointer:]` to store it in the container classes.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
SomeObject *object = [[SomeObject alloc] init];

//Store the pointer to object
[dictionary setValue:[NSValue valueWithPointer:object] forKey:@"object"];
```